# How to set log locale and latency for AsyncNCSARequestLog

Tags: java, logging, jetty

While `AsyncNCSARequestLog` is deprecated I should replace it with `CustomRequestLog`.

The code is:

```
AsyncNCSARequestLog log = new AsyncNCSARequestLog(filename);
log.setAppend(true);
log.setLogLatency(true);
log.setRetainDays(retainDays);
log.setLogLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Supposed to be:

```
AsyncRequestLogWriter writer = new AsyncRequestLogWriter(filename, new BlockingArrayQueue<>(size));
writer.setAppend(true);
writer.setRetainDays(retainDays);
CustomRequestLog log = new CustomRequestLog(writer, CustomRequestLog.EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT);
```

But there is no option to set log locale and latency for `CustomRequestLog` or `AsyncRequestLogWriter`.
How can I set them?

**UPDATED:**

Following settings are gone:

```
AsyncNCSARequestLog log = new AsyncNCSARequestLog(filename, new BlockingArrayQueue<>());
log.setLogDateFormat(format);
log.setExtended(true);
log.setLogLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
log.setLogCookies(true);
log.setLogLatency(true);
log.setLogServer(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented in the [apidocs for CustomRequestLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html).

Locale is only used for "time" representation.

That is specified in the format parameter.

See: `%{format|timeZone|locale}t`

Latency is also a format parameter.

See:

- `%D` for latency in microseconds
- `%T` for latency in seconds
- `%{UNIT}T` for latency in your own desired unit

  - `%msT` is milliseconds
  - `%usT` is microseconds
  - `%sT` is seconds

You'll want to use a custom format parameter, and not the predefined standard format of `CustomRequestLog.EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT` (which never has latency, and always uses `Locale.getDefault()` for its time representation)